# PHP - get PageSpeed (on Apache) configured module filters

Tags: php, apache, mod-pagespeed

I would like to detect the filters configured in the PageSpeed module for Apache. Right now, I can detect if PageSpeed is installed with this:

```
define("MOD_PAGESPEED", (function () {
    $output = false;

    if (function_exists("apache_get_modules")) {
        if (in_array("mod_pagespeed", apache_get_modules(), true)) {
            $output = true;
        }
    } elseif (function_exists("get_headers")) {
        if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])) {
            if (!empty($headers = get_headers((isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}" . ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?? null)))) {
                if (!empty($headers["X-Mod-Pagespeed"]) || !empty($headers["X-Page-Speed"])) {
                    $output = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
})());
```

So far, so good. But now comes the second part. ¿is there a way to get the specific filters configuration?

Comment: by get you mean you wanna list down the active filters on the module through php. coz it's a server side configuration and has to be dealt with the apache or nginx way

Comment: @chandlerbing correct, I want to get an array with the active filters so I can detect which specific features have been defined or enabled.

Comment: i don't really think php provides any built in function to list active config for any particular enabled module... what you can do, though it's not secure at all, is parse your config file in your php file... why would you have such requirements anyway..???